# could not broadcast input array from shape (3,) into shape (500,500)

Tags: python, opencv

I printed out a blank image on OpenCV, and tried to color it.

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#blank image
blank = np.zeros((500,500), dtype = 'uint8') # uint8 is a blank image

cv2.imshow('Blank', blank)

#displaying normal image
#img = cv2.imread('C:\Downloads\wallpaper.jpg')

#cv2.imshow('papier', img)

#Paint the image a certain color

blank[:] = 0,0,255

cv.imshow('Blue', blank)


cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Here is the error I get:

> Exception has occurred: ValueError
> could not broadcast input array from shape (3,) into shape (500,500)
> File "C:\opencv\summer project\draw.py", line 16, in 
> blank[:] = 0,0,255

Can someone please help me?

Comment: In your own words, where you have `np.zeros((500,500), dtype = 'uint8')`, what do you expect that to mean? How did you choose the `dtype` and the dimensions of `(500, 500)`? How exactly is this intended to represent an image - what is the format of the pixels? Now, where you have `blank[:] = 0,0,255`, how did you choose the values `0, 0, 255`? What do they represent - what is the format of the pixel? Do you see how that is incompatible with the original description? Now, which part of that is wrong for your purpose?

Comment: You are creating an image of size 500 x 500, but with how many channels? If BGR, you need to specify the number of channels — (500,500,3): `blank = np.zeros((height,width,channels), np.uint8)`

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# blank image
blank = np.zeros((500, 500, 3), dtype='uint8')  # uint8 is a blank image
cv2.imshow('Blank', blank)

# displaying normal image
# img = cv2.imread('C:\Downloads\wallpaper.jpg')

# cv2.imshow('papier', img)

# Paint the image a certain color

blank[:] = (255, 0, 0)

cv2.imshow('Blue', blank)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Key points are two:

1. 500,500,3: as stateMachine stated, You need channels to make 'blank'.
2. BGR: RGB is familliar order of colors. Because of it, You tried (0,0,255). But OpenCV usually uses BGR. You should have tried (255,0,0).